# Find the average price for all the products from the USA supplier Using SQL

Tags: sql

Hello there internet so I am working on a SQL project in it i need to get the AVG price of products being supplied by the USA. There are two table I am working with one is called Products and the other Suppliers and they're connected by SupplierID. I'm attaching a link to the DBA I'm using as well as the code I've used so you can see where I am at. 
Thanks in advance for any help given!

DBA I Am Using:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

My Code:
SELECT Products.Price, Suppliers.SupplierID
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Suppliers
ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID AND Country = 'USA';

Answer (score 1):

From the query you've posted, it's clear that you understand the need to join the `Products` and `Suppliers` tables so that you can determine each product's country of origin.

One change you should make here, however, is to use an `INNER JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN`. The difference being that an `INNER JOIN` will only return a result where it exists in both tables.

From there you can use the `AVG()` function.

```
SELECT AVG(Products.Price) AS AveragePrice
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID AND Suppliers.Country = 'USA';
```

Comment: I understand thank you so much as you mentioned I knew i had to join the two table just was unclear which join to use and how to find the avg once they were joined. Thanks again!!

Comment: I mean a `LEFT JOIN` would work, but would have the side-effect of including any products without suppliers in the result. You wouldn't want this to happen, because without the supplier, you can't be sure the product came from the USA. An `INNER JOIN` prevents this.